# Run two animations simultaneously in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt

I have created two separate functions to animate my title image. One makes it move down slightly, the other fades it in (increases the opacity). Independently they both work, but together, only the opacity one is actually ran. How would I make them both run at the same time?

**Movement Function:**

```
def title_intro(self):
        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.ui.title_image, b"geometry")
        self.animation.setDuration(500)
        self.animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(190, -60, 671, 261))
        self.animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(190, 0, 671, 261))
        self.animation.start()
```

**Opacity Function:**

```
def title_intro_opacity(self):
        self.opacity_effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.ui.title_image.setGraphicsEffect(self.opacity_effect)

        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.opacity_effect, b"opacity")
        self.animation.setDuration(500)
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(1)
        self.animation.start()
```

**Project Code (for context):**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuick
import sys
import platform

from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.title_intro()
        self.title_intro_opacity()
        self.show()

    def title_intro(self):
        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.ui.title_image, b"geometry")
        self.animation.setDuration(500)
        self.animation.setStartValue(QtCore.QRect(190, -60, 671, 261))
        self.animation.setEndValue(QtCore.QRect(190, 0, 671, 261))
        self.animation.start()
    
    def title_intro_opacity(self):
        self.opacity_effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.ui.title_image.setGraphicsEffect(self.opacity_effect)

        self.animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(self.opacity_effect, b"opacity")
        self.animation.setDuration(500)
        self.animation.setStartValue(0)
        self.animation.setEndValue(1)
        self.animation.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Entire Class:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1070, 720)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("Game Graphics/CCM logo circle.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.background_title_image = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.background_title_image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1071, 741))
        self.background_title_image.setStyleSheet("border-image: url(:/newPrefix/background image.png);")
        self.background_title_image.setText("")
        self.background_title_image.setScaledContents(True)
        self.background_title_image.setObjectName("background_title_image")
        self.title_image = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.title_image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 0, 671, 261))
        self.title_image.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.title_image.setStyleSheet("image: url(:/newPrefix/clash clan manager text.png);")
        self.title_image.setText("")
        self.title_image.setScaledContents(True)
        self.title_image.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.title_image.setObjectName("title_image")
        self.log_in_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.log_in_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 330, 381, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Supercell-Magic")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.log_in_button.setFont(font)
        self.log_in_button.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.log_in_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.125, y1:0.471909, x2:0.938, y2:0.472, stop:0         rgba(49, 87, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(38, 168, 255, 255)); \n"
"    color: white;\n"
"     border-radius: 10; \n"
"    padding: 6; \n"
"    border-style: outset;\n"
"    border-width: 1;\n"
"    border-top-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);\n"
"    border-left-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);\n"
"    border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"    border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: outset;\n"
"    border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"    border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"    border-right-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);\n"
"    border-bottom-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);\n"
"    \n"
"}")
        self.log_in_button.setCheckable(False)
        self.log_in_button.setChecked(False)
        self.log_in_button.setDefault(False)
        self.log_in_button.setFlat(False)
        self.log_in_button.setObjectName("log_in_button")
        self.sign_up_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.sign_up_button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 430, 381, 81))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Supercell-Magic")
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.sign_up_button.setFont(font)
        self.sign_up_button.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.sign_up_button.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.125, y1:0.466, x2:0.938, y2:0.472, stop:0 rgba(0, 144, 24, 255), stop:1 rgba(124, 255, 38, 255));\n"
"    color: white;\n"
"     border-radius: 10; \n"
"    padding: 6; \n"
"    border-style: outset;\n"
"    border-width: 1;\n"
"    border-top-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);\n"
"    border-left-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);\n"
"    border-right-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"    border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"    \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    border-style: outset;\n"
"    border-top-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"    border-left-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);\n"
"    border-right-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);\n"
"    border-bottom-color: rgb(135, 135, 135);\n"
"    \n"
"}")
        self.sign_up_button.setCheckable(False)
        self.sign_up_button.setChecked(False)
        self.sign_up_button.setDefault(False)
        self.sign_up_button.setFlat(False)
        self.sign_up_button.setObjectName("sign_up_button")
        self.background_title_image.raise_()
        self.title_image.raise_()
        self.sign_up_button.raise_()
        self.log_in_button.raise_()
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1070, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Clash Clan Manager"))
        self.log_in_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LOG IN"))
        self.sign_up_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SIGN UP"))
import source


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllanesc it's pretty large as it was generated with Qt designer. Do you want the entire thing or just a specific part?

Comment: @eyllanesc edited the post to include the entire class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning 2 objects to the same variable so the previous object is eliminated. In this case it is not necessary that both are attributes, also an improvement is to use QParallelAnimationGroup:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.start_animation()
        self.show()

    def start_animation(self):
        opacity_effect = QtWidgets.QGraphicsOpacityEffect(self.ui.title_image)
        self.ui.title_image.setGraphicsEffect(opacity_effect)

        geometry_animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            self.ui.title_image,
            b"geometry",
            duration=500,
            startValue=QtCore.QRect(190, -60, 671, 261),
            endValue=QtCore.QRect(190, 0, 671, 261),
        )

        opacity_animation = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(
            opacity_effect, b"opacity", duration=500, startValue=0.0, endValue=1.0
        )

        group = QtCore.QParallelAnimationGroup(self.ui.title_image)
        group.addAnimation(geometry_animation)
        group.addAnimation(opacity_animation)
        group.start(QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```